# combine datetime and milisecond

Tags: python, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a table in `x.db` file which has two columns. One column is of type `datetime` and the other is of type `millisecond`. I need to read both columns as one in python.

[sample datetime and millisecond attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fEye.png)

I want to read the `datetime`(this will be my `x` value for the plot) as

```
2022-05-25 14:20:26.948

2022-05-25 14:20:26.968

2022-05-25 14:20:26.988

2022-05-25 14:20:27.008

2022-05-25 14:20:26.028

2022-05-25 14:20:26.048
```

so I can plot the desired data in millisecond.

The code that I am trying to build is here

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('./x.db')

cur = conn.cursor()


cur.execute('select * from data ')
tmp_row = cur.fetchall()
#print(tmp_row)

conn.close()
xdate=[]
abc=[]
dfg=[]


for row in tmp_row:
    tmp=row[0]
    yy=tmp[0]+tmp[1]+tmp[2]+tmp[3]
    mm=tmp[5]+tmp[6]
    dd=tmp[8]+tmp[9]
    HH=tmp[11]+tmp[12]
    MM=tmp[14]+tmp[15]
    ss=tmp[17]+tmp[18]

    tmp2=row[1]
    print(tmp2)
    t=tmp2[0]+tmp2[1]+tmp2[2]



    tmpdt=dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy+" "+HH+":"+MM+":"+ss+"."+t
    #print(tmpdt)
   
    #print(tmpdt)
```

The error I am getting is

> t=tmp2[0]+tmp2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fEye.png)+tmp2[2] TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Another problem is that some have single digit value. I need to add `00` in front while concating
timestamp_S                t_ms

```
2022-05-25 14:20:27    8
```

required is

```
2022-05-25 14:20:27.008
```

Comment: tmp2 is a Python *int*. You should also research Python string slicing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime` and `datetime.datetime.replace` functions to get what you wanted.

```
from datetime import datetime

for row in tmp_row:
    t = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  # t = datetime(2022, 5, 25, 14, 20, 26)
    t = t.replace(microsecond = int(row[1]) * 1000)     # t = datetime(2022, 5, 25, 14, 20, 26, 948000)
    print(str(t)[:23])) # str(t) = "2022-05-25 14:20:26.948000", str(t)[:23] = "2022-05-25 14:20.26.948"
```